# Cross validation with CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, cross-validation

I would like to know if my code is doing what  i want to do; To give you some background 'im implementing CNN for image classification. I'm trying to use cross validation to compare my different neural network architecture

here the code:

```
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(24,kernel_size=3,padding='same',activation='relu',
            input_shape=(96,96,1)))
    model.add(MaxPool2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(48,kernel_size=3,padding='same',activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,padding='same',activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D())
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(12, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=5, batch_size=20, verbose=1) 
# 3-Fold Crossvalidation
kfold = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=2019) 
results = cross_val_score(model, train_X, train_Y_one_hot, cv=kfold)

model.fit(train_X, train_Y_one_hot,validation_data=(valid_X, valid_label),class_weight=class_weights)
y_pred = model.predict(test_X)

test_eval = model.evaluate(test_X, y_pred, verbose=0)
```

I have found the part for cross validation on internet. But i have some problem to understand it.

My question: 1=> Can I use cross validation to improve my accuracy? For example i run 10 time my neural network and my model get the weight where the best accuracy occured

2 => If i understand well, in the code above, **results** run my CNN 3 time and show me the accuracy. But when i use **model.fit**, model is run only one time; Am i right?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not really, cross-validation is more a way to prevent overfitting/ not be confused by abnormal results coming from a badly splitted dataset -> getting a revelant estimation of you model performances. If you want to tune the Hyperparameters of your model, you should better use `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV` / `sklearn.model_selection.RandomSearchCV`
2. when doing `cross_val_score` For each Train/Test 
   sklearn does a `fit` then `predict`/`evaluate`, So for each new Instance of the model,
   you have 1 `fit` then 1 `predict`/`evaluate`;
   Else your cross-validation is not valid because it depends on fitting on previous dataset (and maybe on test data !)

Answer (score 1):

There are two key terms here that you should get familiarized with:

1. Hyperparameters
2. Parameters

Hyperparameters control the general architecture of a model. These are what the programmer or data scientist controls. In case of a CNN, this refers to the number of layers, their configurations, activations, optimizers etc. For a simple polynomial regression model this would be the degree of the polynomial.

Parameters refer to the actual values of weights or coefficients that the model ends up with after it solves the optimization using gradient descent or whatever method you use. In a CNN this would be the weights matrix for each layer. For a polynomial regression this would be the coefficients and bias.

Cross validation is used to find the best set of hyperparameters. The best set of parameters are obtained by the optimizer (gradient descent, adam etc) for a *given* set of hyperparameters and data.

To answer your questions:

1. You would run cross validation several times, each time with a different hyperparameter configuration (network architecture). That's the only thing you can control. At the end you pick the best architecture based on accuracy. The weights of the model would be different for each fold but finding the best weights is the optimizer's job, not yours.
2. Yes. In 3 fold CV, the model is trained 3 times and evaluated 3 times. When you do `model.fit` you are making predictions *once* on a new dataset.